# Assign SQL schema to Spark DataFrame

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm converting my team's legacy Redshift SQL code to Spark SQL code. All the Spark examples I've seen define the schema in a non-SQL way using `StructType` and `StructField` and I'd prefer to define the schema in SQL, since most of my users know SQL but not Spark.

This is the ugly workaround I'm doing now. Is there a more elegant way that doesn't require defining an empty table just so that I can pull the SQL schema?

```
create_table_sql = '''
CREATE TABLE public.example (
  id LONG,
  example VARCHAR(80)
)'''
spark.sql(create_table_sql)
schema = spark.sql("DESCRIBE public.example").collect()
s3_data = spark.read.\
option("delimiter", "|")\
.csv(
    path="s3a://"+s3_bucket_path,
    schema=schema
)\
.saveAsTable('public.example')
```

Comment: Why can't you do `create table public.new AS (select * from public.example where 1=0)`? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @pault because the source data (csv) in S3 does not also persist datatypes along with the values. I suspect Spark could infer some of the types, but some of my columns are decimals that I need to track with high precision, so I want to be explicit about how the columns are defined.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a way to create schema from string although I am not sure if it really looks like SQL! So you can use:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import _parse_datatype_string

_parse_datatype_string("id: long, example: string")
```

This will create the next schema:

```
  StructType(List(StructField(id,LongType,true),StructField(example,StringType,true)))
```

Or you may have a complex schema as well:

```
schema = _parse_datatype_string("customers array<struct<id: long, name: string, address: string>>")

StructType(
  List(StructField(
    customers,ArrayType(
      StructType(
        List(
          StructField(id,LongType,true),
          StructField(name,StringType,true),
          StructField(address,StringType,true)
        )
      ),true),true)
  )
)
```

You can check for more examples [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad-spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/tests.py)

***UPDATE: 23 March 2023***

In the case of json string use [_parse_datatype_json_string](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/04202b3fdda1ac7aea7d7e5688487ce749ad2f79/python/pyspark/sql/types.py#L1243) as shown next:

```py
schema_json = """{"fields": [
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "id",
            "nullable": true,
            "type": "long"
        },
        {
            "metadata": {},
            "name": "example",
            "nullable": true,
            "type": "string"
        }],
    "type": "struct"}"""
_parse_datatype_json_string(schema_json)

# StructType(List(StructField(id,LongType,true),StructField(example,StringType,true)))
```

Answer (score 0):

adding up to what has already been said, making a schema (e.g. StructType-based or JSON) is more straightforward in scala spark than in pySpark:

```scala
> import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

> val s = StructType.fromDDL("customers array<struct<id: long, name: string, address: string>>")

> s

res3: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(customers,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(id,LongType,true),StructField(name,StringType,true),StructField(address,StringType,true)),true),true))

> s.prettyJson
res9: String =
{
  "type" : "struct",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "customers",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "elementType" : {
        "type" : "struct",
        "fields" : [ {
          "name" : "id",
          "type" : "long",
          "nullable" : true,
          "metadata" : { }
        }, {
          "name" : "name",
          "type" : "string",
          "nullable" : true,
          "metadata" : { }
        }, {
          "name" : "address",
          "type" : "string",
          "nullable" : true,
          "metadata" : { }
        } ]
      },
      "containsNull" : true
    },
    "nullable" : true,
    "metadata" : { }
  } ]
}
```