# Get dataframe schema load to metadata table

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Use case is to read a file and create a dataframe on top of it.After that get the schema of that file and store into a DB table.

For example purpose I am just creating a case class and getting the printschema however I am unable create a dataframe out of it

Here is a sample code

```
case class Employee(Name:String, Age:Int, Designation:String, Salary:Int, ZipCode:Int)

val spark = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName("Spark SQL basic example")
.config("spark.master", "local")
.getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
val EmployeesData = Seq( Employee("Anto",   21, "Software Engineer", 2000, 56798))
val Employee_DataFrame = EmployeesData.toDF
val dfschema = Employee_DataFrame.schema
```

Now dfschema is a structype and wanted to convert it in a dataframe of two columns , how to achieve that

Comment: dfschema is of structtype with 5 columns as defined in the case class. what 2 columns do you want to convert to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.4.0**

In order to save the schema into a string format you can use the `toDDL` method of the `StructType`. In your case the DDL format should be:

```
`Name` STRING, `Age` INT, `Designation` STRING, `Salary` INT, `ZipCode` INT
```

After saving the schema you can load it from the database and use it as `StructType.fromDDL(my_schema)` this will return an instance of StructType which you can use to create the new dataframe with `spark.createDataFrame` as @Ajay already mentioned.

Also is useful to remember that you can always [extract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36746055/generate-a-spark-structtype-schema-from-a-case-class) the schema given a case class with:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
val empSchema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Employee].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

And then you can get the DDL representation with `empSchema.toDDL`.

**Spark < 2.4**

For Spark < 2.4 use `DataType.fromDDL` and `schema.simpleString` accordingly. Also instead of returning  a `StructType` you should use an `DataType` instance  omitting the cast to StructType as next:

```
val empSchema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[Employee].dataType
```

Sample output for empSchema.simpleString:

```
struct<Name:string,Age:int,Designation:string,Salary:int,ZipCode:int>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , one thing I notice toDDL method introduced in spark 2.4

Comment: True Pratik, fromDDL exists since 2.2.0 though. Which version are you using?

Comment: Hi Pratik I modified  the answer for older version as well

Comment: you welcome Pratik, let me know if it worked for you

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can you please let me know similar function like toDDL or simplestring exists for python as well ?

Comment: Yes there is a similar functionality for pyspark as well check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972609/assign-sql-schema-to-spark-dataframe/55976814#55976814

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
//-- For local file
val rdd = spark.read.option("wholeFile", true).option("delimiter",",").csv(s"file:///file/path/file.csv").rdd

val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("Name", StringType, true),
                            StructField("Age", IntegerType, true),
                            StructField("Designation", StringType, true),
                            StructField("Salary", IntegerType, true),
                            StructField("ZipCode", IntegerType, true)))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
```