# Get field values from a structtype in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have to get the schema from a csv file (the column name and datatype).I have reached so far -

```python
l = [('Alice', 1)]
Person = Row('name', 'age')
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
person = rdd.map(lambda r: Person(*r))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(person)
print(df2.schema)
#StructType(List(StructField(name,StringType,true),StructField(age,LongType,true)))
```

I want to extract the values `name` and `age` along with `StringType` and `LongType` however I don't see any method on struct type.

There's `toDDL` method of struct type in scala but the same is not available for python.

This is an extension of the mentioned question where I already got help , however I wanted to create a new thread -
[Get dataframe schema load to metadata table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56796668/get-dataframe-schema-load-to-metadata-table)

Thanks for the reply , I am updating the full code -

```python
import pyspark # only run after findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory") \
    .getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql import Row
l = [('Alice', 1)]
Person = Row('name', 'age')
rdd = sc.parallelize(l)
person = rdd.map(lambda r: Person(*r))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(person)
df3=df2.dtypes
df1=spark.createDataFrame(df3, ['colname', 'datatype'])
df1.show()
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
spark.sql('''select * from test ''').show()
```

Output

```python
+-------+--------+
|colname|datatype|
+-------+--------+
|   name|  string|
|    age|  bigint|
+-------+--------+

+-------+--------+
|colname|datatype|
+-------+--------+
|   name|  string|
|    age|  bigint|
+-------+--------+
```

Comment: I am confused by your latest edit - did you answer your own question?

Answer (score 4):

IIUC, you can loop over the values in `df2.schema.fields` and get the `name` and `dataType`:

```python
print([(x.name, x.dataType) for x in df2.schema.fields])
#[('name', StringType), ('age', LongType)]
```

There is also `dtypes`:

```python
print(df2.dtypes)
#[('name', 'string'), ('age', 'bigint')]
```

and you may also be interested in `printSchema()`:

```python
df2.printSchema()
#root
# |-- name: string (nullable = true)
# |-- age: long (nullable = true)
```

Comment: what about functions like .toDDL() from scala in PySpark

Comment: you could try something like: ddl = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType.fromJson(schema_json).toDDL()